# Reverse proxy CORS Configuration for NGINX

Tags: nginx, proxy, configuration, cors

I have a nodejs server and react client app deployed to an ec2 instance.  When I try to send a POST request to /api/emails route it returns a CORS / CORB error in the console.

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9001/api/email. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

My app-server nginx configuration looks like:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name ec2-52-202-82-153.compute-1.amazonaws.com;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' true;
     }
}
```

My app-client configuration looks like:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name ec2-52-202-82-153.compute-1.amazonaws.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9002;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

```
if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    #
    # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
    #
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
    #
    # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
    #
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    return 204;
 }
```

if you put this in your `app-server` location it will see that it is a pre-flight request and return instantly with a 204. You will have to play with all of the different headers to get it to what you want.

*Please Note This does assume that your `nginx` configs are setup up correctly as you have two server blocks with the same `server_name`*